# Is it possible to separate the repository containing jenkinsfile from the repository containing the code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I created the following `jenkinsfile` with the help of `Blue Ocean`:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('git') {
      steps {
        git(url: 'git-url-to-code', branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'gitjenkins')
        
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        sshagent(credentials: ['cert']) {
          sh 'ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@machine ls -trl'
          sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@machine rm -rf /apps/shiny/spielMA/ '
          sh 'scp -rp  ./. user@machine:/apps/shiny/spielMA/'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it dose not work. to be more precise, my jenkins code is in repository **J** und der Code in the repo **C** and it can not trigger the pipeline if I push newe code in master in **C**!
Is there any possibility to trigger the pipeline, with a jenkinscode which is not in the repository of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the [Remote Jenkinsfile Provider](https://plugins.jenkins.io/remote-file/) plugin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).